# How to deleteInBatch with CrudRepository by @Id?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'd like to make use of springs `CrudRepository.deleteInBatch(List<Entity>)`.

**Problem:** I have to feed this method with the entity objects. I want to execute a select query that returns approx 10k entities.

```
dao.findAllByAge()
```

**Question:** could I somehow just return the `@Id`s from the `findBy` query, and use these IDs to `deleteInBatch` instead?

Comment: Yes you can. But why would you do that?

Comment: Could you point out how this would be done with spring-data-jpa? My main reson would be that my `Entity` contains many `eager` lists that are fetched on select. If I first select all entities, all the data would be fetched from db. Which takes a long time and could be avoided by just fetching the `@Id`s and `deleteInBatch` by a list of IDs.

Comment: I'm asking because `deleteInBatch()` only takes a `List<Entity>`, not a `List<Long>`.

Comment: This makes sense, since some entities are large and you may have memory constraints. Being able to delete with a list of ID's enables you to load less into memory before performing the batch operation.

Answer (score 1):

The query derivation currently doesn't support projections (see [DATACMNS-89](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-89) for details and progress), but reading the objects should be needed in the first place. You could just declare a a dedicated delete query for that:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("delete from User u where …")
Long deleteBy…(…)
```

That will execute the query  on the database directly and thus execute the delete in a batch. Note however, that this will not trigger any lifecycle callbacks on the affected entities as they're not loaded in the first place.